# Android wear: sensortypes not described

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors

There a serveral sensors in my android wear LG Wear wich are not described in the android documentation:

Sensorname: AMD, Type: 33171006
Sensorname: RMD , Sensortyp: 33171007
Sensorname: Basic Gestures, Sensortyp: 33171000
Sensorname: Facing , Sensortyp: 33171002
Sensorname: Tilt , Sensortyp: 33171003
Sensorname: Pedometer , Sensortyp: 33171009
Sensorname: TiltWakeUp , Sensortyp: 65536
Sensorname: pixart_ppg , Sensortyp: 33171018
Sensorname: pixart_ppg_raw , Sensortyp: 33171017

May someone know more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess AMD means Absolute Motion Detection (AMD), RMD means Relative Motion Detection (RMD).

> Absolute Motion Detection (AMD): This feature will report the absolute motion state when the device is disturbed from a state of complete rest or no motion. A device on the dash of a moving car will report that the device is in motion.
>
> Relative Motion Detection (RMD): This feature will report the motion state relative to the environment of the device. A device on the dash of a moving car will report that the device is at rest relative to the vehicle.
>
> Activity Recognition: This feature is not included in this SDK release, but will be included in an update release. It provides classifications of the motion state that includes Stationary, Vehicle, Walk, and Run.

These sensors are with Snapdragon chips.

More details, please see this : https://developer.qualcomm.com/blog/sensors-and-snapdragon-sdk-early-access